# Stripe material with a constant stripe

Tags: materials

I would like to create a stripe material where the widths of the individual stripes are constant when scaled.

For example, create a cylinder with a z scale of 2m ... this might have say four stripes (2 blue, 2 yellow). Each stripe would therefore be 50cm.
Resize the cylinder to 6m. There would be 12 stripes where each stripe is still 50cm.

Rotating the cylinder should not change the stripes.

Is this possible?

Thanks.